# custom sort and feature on the table head

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have build a custom table component, but here i am not using a common state for doing the actions. So i am just listing the issues here where i am stucked.

1. I Search for `do` in name column, only one results comes up, but if i click on sort, it will sort the entire data, so here the problem is i should use the common variable for filter and sort how should i do it
2. also like the sort have a custom function same way need to have for the search, how should i incoperate it, like a prop for it so search can be done in a custom way like sort
3. Also how can i close the search input on clicking outside and clear and make it active sort whichever is the current active

**Additional**

1. adding a no data container when no results , is that correct way how can i make it proper
2. how can i refactor the code in a cleaner way using hooks

This the main section where i feel changes required

```
useEffect(() => {
    const currentSortedData = sortData(tableData, sortings);
    dispatch({ sortedData: currentSortedData });
  }, [tableData, sortings]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!searchString) {
      const currentSortedData = sortData(tableData, sortings);
      dispatch({ sortedData: currentSortedData });
    }
  }, [searchString]);
```

I have added what i have tried, and achieved

Working [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-component-filter-and-sort-rgmub)